# Нужно написать(отредактировать мой) SQL запрос

Tags: sql, sqlite

Структуры таблиц:

> Persons(person_id, name)
>   Product(product_id, name)
>   Deals(id,product_id,person_id)

Найти имена людей(Person), которые заключали сделки(deals) на все продукты.

Мой SQL запрос: (не рабочий)

```
SELECT persons.name from persons
WHERE
(
 (SELECT DISTINCT deals.product_id from deals 
        WHERE deals.person_id = persons.person_id)
        =
       (SELECT products.product_id from products)
)
```

Comment: а что значит заключали сделки? т.е. в табличке Deals, есть запись с person_id ?

Answer (score 0):

Создание таблиц:

```
create table persons(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    _name varchar(25)
);

create table products(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    _name varchar(25)
);

create table deals(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    product_id int references products.id,
    person_id int references persons.id
);
```

Заполнение:

```
insert into persons
(_name)
VALUES
    ('Oleg'),
    ('Tanya'),
    ('Nadya');

insert into products
(_name)
VALUES
    ('bread'),
    ('water'),
    ('solt');


insert into deals
(product_id, person_id)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 1),
    (2, 1),

    (1, 2),
    (2, 2),
    (2, 2);
```

Идея запроса в следующем - сравнить количество уникальных продуктов вообще и количество уникальных продуктов, купленных данным человеком. Если эти величины равны, то этот человек купил все возможные товары.

Запрос:

```
SELECT
    _name
FROM
    persons
WHERE
    (SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            product_id 
        FROM 
            deals 
        WHERE 
            person_id = persons.id
        GROUP BY product_id) as t)
    =
    (SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        (SELECT
            id
        FROM
            products
        GROUP BY id) as t)
```

Вывод:

> _name
>   Oleg

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT persons.name from persons t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deals s WHERE s.person_id = t.person_id)
```

мог лажануть с синтаксисом)

Comment: что значит "select 1" ?

Comment: Это вы выбираете всех, кто сделал хотя бы одну покупку

Comment: @user351599 да без разницы, что писать. Его конструкция `exists` не интересуется, что нам вернулось - она интересуется, если кто-нибудь, кто прошел условие `where`.